# jQuery isotope; all images don't load on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I hope this is relevant and appropriate question. I have a portfolio at http://planetoidi.com and it works great on any desktop. However, when I view the site on Lumia 920 only a random selection of portfolio items display the image. All items are loaded but some fail to load their "cover image". This doesn't seem to have any correlation, different images load on refresh. Any ideas?

Also, is it possible to have some sort of animation even to those items that don't move in their place? Id like all the items to animate somehow because at the moment switching portfolio filters isn't always visually notable.